# Customising Jersey JSON marshalling for java.util.Maps

Tags: java, json, jersey

By default, marshalling a `@XmlRootElement` bean containing a map gives the structure:

```
myMap : {
    entry : {
        key : {
            ...
        },
        value : {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to customise the JSON field names 'entry', 'key' and 'value'?

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom [`@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html). [@Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan) has a [clearly-written tutorial](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html) on using them.

See also [`XmlAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html).